# в WebView при открытии видео с VK.com есть звук, но нет видео

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, видео, android-webview, android-vksdk

Делаю приложение на андроид для просмотра видео с личной странички в **VK**.
Прохожу все авторизации и соглашаюсь на доступ к данным.

Список всех видео выводится в **RecyclerView**.
При тапе на елемент списка делаю переход в новое активити. При этом получаю ссылку на плеер который должен открыть видео в **fullscreen** режиме во **WebView**.

Плеер загружается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимая на стрелку происходит следующее:
1) движется полоса прокрутки видео.
2) есть звук.
3) не отображается видео.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.devtolife.vkvideoline">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:name=".Aplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKServiceActivity"
        android:label="ServiceActivity"
        android:theme="@style/VK.Transparent" />
    <activity
        android:name="FullActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.openVideo" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity:

```
public class FullActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full);
        String vidString = getIntent().getStringExtra("urlOfVKPlayer");

        WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.video_play);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadData(vidString, "text/html", "UTF-8");

        mWebView.loadUrl(vidString);

    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/video_play"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Пробовал включать выключать следующие строки и в разных комбинациях:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.loadData(vidString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Просмотрел похожие темы, но там в большинстве случаев реализация схожа с моей.

Тестировал на реальном устройстве - так как на нем есть доступ к ВК через VPN.
Устройство: Samsung GT-i8552,
Разрешение: 480 x 800 (WVGA),
Операционная система: Android, 4.1,
Форматы видео:MP3,AAC,AAC+,eAAC+,M4A,3GA,OGG,FLAC,WAV,WMA,AMR-WB,AMR-NB,MIDI,SP-MIDI,XMF,i-Melod.

Весь код приложения на гите: https://github.com/vmarch/VKVideoLine.git

Подскажите может кто сталкивался.

Comment: А в стандартном браузере это видео отображается?

Comment: Да, отображается в мобайл версии сайта. Но возник второй момент что именно я получаю. Сейчас еще буду играться с разрешением видео.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш WebView не умеет воспроизводить h264.
Попробуйте [обновить](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=ru) и переключиться на него в инструментах для разработчиков. Так же можете скачать любое видео в h264 и попытаться воспроизвести: любым плеером на телефоне, вашим приложением на эмуляторе.

Comment: Фактически да, телефон не поддерживает h264. Но, покуда я знаю, то и VK не использует h264. У Них FLV и MP4.  Обновление которое Вы предложили - для версий под андроид 5+. У меня же версия 4.1.2.

Comment: Все верно, MP4 в h264 контейнере. У меня такая же проблема была в убунте, пока не поставил codecs-ffmpeg-extra

Comment: Впринципе, поковырявшись в гугле, пришел к тому что на версии андроид 4.1. без кастомных библиотек (помимо VKAPI) просмотр потокового видео реализовать неполучится. Потому впринципе можно считать что даный ответ помог  найти решение моей проблеммы.